# data wrangling: how can i filter rows with multiple values? or other ways to handle nested values

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr

when i use pivot_wider() on my data, there are some numeric values that are duplicates, forcing conversion to a list with nested values.

here's an example:

```
dfx <- data.frame("Arb_PersonID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                  "LabComponentName" = c("2ch", "4ch", "2ch", "4ch", "2ch", "4ch"), 
                  "LabResult" = c(56, 55, 50, 54, 56, 60))

class(dfx1$`2ch`)
```

this shows:

```
> tibble(dfx)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Arb_PersonID LabComponentName LabResult
         <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>
1            1 2ch                     56
2            1 4ch                     55
3            2 2ch                     50
4            2 4ch                     54
5            2 2ch                     56
6            2 4ch                     60

> class(dfx$LabResult)
[1] "numeric"
```

Then pivot_wider:

```
dfx1 <- dfx %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = LabComponentName, values_from = LabResult)



  Arb_PersonID `2ch`     `4ch`    
             1  56         55
             2  c(50,56)  c(54,60)

> class(dfx1$`2ch`)
[1] "list"
```

I'd like to use the average of the 2 values (ie 53 instead of c(50,56)) and keep the class numeric.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm using a very large dataset of 14,000 rows and these duplicates are about 1/500. Manually reviewing and correcting is quite painful, but not impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handy `values_fn` option within the `pivot_wider` call which will allow you do simply do the mean whenever there are multiple values:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfx <- data.frame("Arb_PersonID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                  "LabComponentName" = c("2ch", "4ch", "2ch", "4ch", "2ch", "4ch"), 
                  "LabResult" = c(56, 55, 50, 54, 56, 60))

dfx %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = LabComponentName, values_from = LabResult,
              values_fn = mean)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   Arb_PersonID `2ch` `4ch`
#>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1            1    56    55
#> 2            2    53    57
```

Comment: works perfectly. can't tell you how much time/effort you just saved me, thanks a ton!

Comment: I always enjoy that the `tidyverse` functions often seem to have a single option for that little task you were trying to figure out :)